# Javascript Array.slice() vs Array.slice(0)

Tags: javascript, slice

Some time ago I saw somewhere the thing that Array.slice(0) is faster than Array.slice(). Unfortunately now I can't find that source. So is that possible ? There is any difference between Array.slice(0) and Array.slice() ?

Comment: If no parrameter is provided the `slice` assumes it's  `0`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no difference, because `begin` is assigned to `0` by default if you don't provide any parameter to `Array.slice()` method.

> **begin** `Optional`
>
> Zero-based index at which to begin extraction. A
> negative index can be used, indicating an offset from the end of the
> sequence.
>
> **If begin is undefined, slice begins from index 0.**

*For more info:* [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 5):

`slice` is something like this:

```
function slice(start) {
    if( /* start is not valid */ ) {
        start = 0;
    }
    // ...
}
```

The only diffirence is wether the line `start = 0` is evaluated or not! So the only change in evaluation time will be that of the assignment which is not very costly comparing it to the rest of the code!

Answer (score 3):

If you won't pass any argument to the `Array.slice()` function, the default state will be set to `0`.

*If begin is undefined, slice begins from index 0.*

[Array.prototype.slice() MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)